# How to store data in elasticsearch _source but not index it?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am searching only by couple of fields but I want to be able to store the whole document in ES in order not to additional DB (MySQL) queries.

I tried adding `index: no`, `store: no` to whole objects/properties in the mapping but I'm still not sure if the fields are being indexed and add unnecessary overhead.

Let's say I've got books and each has an author. I want to search only by book title, but I want to be able to retrieve the whole document.

Is this okay:

```
mappings:
properties:
    title:
        type: string
        index: analyzed
    author:
        type: object
        index: no
        store: no
        properties:
            first_name:
                type: string
            last_name:
                type: string
```

Or should I rather do:

```
mappings:
properties:
    title:
        type: string
        index: analyzed
    author:
        type: object
        properties:
            first_name:
                index: no
                store: no
                type: string
            last_name:
                index: no
                store: no
                type: string
```

Or maybe I am doing it completely wrong?
And what about `nested` properties that should not be indexed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default the `_source` of the document is stored regardless of the fields that you choose to index. The `_source` is used to return the document in the search results, whereas the fields that are indexed are used for searching.

You can't set `index: no` on an object to prevent all fields in an object being indexed, but you can do what you want with [Dynamic Templates](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_templates) using `path_match` property to apply the `index: no` setting to every field within an object. Here is a simple example.

Create an index with your mapping that includes the dynamic templates for the `author` object and the nested `categories` object:

```
POST /shop
{
    "mappings": {
        "book": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "author_object_template": {
                        "path_match": "author.*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "no"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "categories_object_template": {
                        "path_match": "categories.*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "no"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "categories": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index a document:

```
POST /shop/book/1
{
    "title": "book one",
    "author": {
        "first_name": "jon",
        "last_name": "doe"
    },
    "categories": [
        {
            "cat_id": 1,
            "cat_name": "category one"
        },
        {
            "cat_id": 2,
            "cat_name": "category two"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you searched on the `title` field with the search term `book` the document would be returned. If you search on the `author.first_name` or `author.last_name`, there won't be a match because this fields were not indexed:

```
POST /shop/book/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "author.first_name": "jon"
        }
    }
}
```

The same would be the case for a nested query on the category fields:

```
POST /shop/book/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "categories",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "categories.cat_name": "category"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can use the [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) tool to expect the Lucene index and see what fields have been indexed.

Comment: Does `"index": "no"` imply `"store": "no"` ? I've read `store` means storing the original property's `_source` in lucene but I'm not sure how it is related to `index`.
And just to make sure - I don't have to provide mappings for the non-indexed fields? ES won't throw errors if I put a document with property X that is an int and then a document with the same property but with string?

Comment: No, the setting for index does not determine the setting for store. The default for store is no, which is fine in your use case because the _source is enabled. If you disabled the _source field and select the fields you want to store, the stored fields will only be returned in the search results when there is a match. You have to provide mapping for non indexed fields in order to tell Elasticsearch not to index them, otherwise Elasticsearch will use the default analyzer (Standard Analyzer) to index the field.

Comment: However, in the above example the dynamic templates are used for the mappings of non indexed fields. If you don't have a mapping for a field an error won't be returned if you change the type of a property.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set **"enabled": false** in mapping definition.

> The [enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) setting, which can be applied only to the top-level mapping definition and to object fields, causes Elasticsearch to skip parsing of the contents of the field entirely. The JSON can still be retrieved from the `_source` field, but it is not searchable or stored in any other way.

```
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "title": { "type": "text" },
    "author": { "type": "object", "enabled": false }
  }
}
```

But beware that `enabled` is not applicable to core types, however `index` option can be applied to core types by setting **"index": false** instead.

> The [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) option controls whether field values are indexed. It accepts true or false and defaults to true. Fields that are not indexed are not queryable.